# Movie with people on Mars, Mars atmosphere has a problem, and guy saves them all with putting hand on some Martian hand engraving on stone?

Tags: story-identification, movie

What's the movie with people living on Mars, the atmosphere I think having a problem, since in the end the atmosphere gets restored(?) cleaned(?) or something, by the guy placing his hand on a stone engraving of a hand of an alien/martian which is something with three fingers I think?

I watched this on HBO sometime 2007 I believe.

Comment: Im sad we live in a world where people dont know Total Recall.

Comment: @user23298 Since many people have seen it, you might say it's a pity they don't _recall_ it.  I'll escort myself out.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is [*Total Recall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Recall_(1990_film)) (1990) starring Arnold Schwarzenegger.

You can see the *four*-finger device in the image below. It starts an air reactor, saving a group of people who're being suffocated by the evil Cohagen.

[image]

Comment: This is it thanks! :D

Comment: If people normally remember just one thing from this movie, it generally is somebody with three body parts. Not normally fingers though!

Comment: I see four fingers on this, though.

Comment: @ths - Three fingers and a thumb, dude.

Comment: How anthropocentric.

Comment: @Richard Apparently, it's not that cut & dry. People can't agree on whether a thumb is a finger, but most definitions admit that some people consider the thumb a finger.

Comment: Haha, I really just remember 3 fingers though :)) Come on I only watched the latter half of the movie back in 2007. So it was 4 fingers. Go figure my memory.

Comment: How can non one link [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5TqD5xf0ic) ?!

Comment: @ThePopMachine Ronny Cox has never looked so good.