# Arnold Schwarzenegger movie of creepy people kidnapping normal kids for some reason

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was an Arnold Schwarzenegger movie in which he saves some kids from a facility which had a big exhaust sort of equipment at the top. There were other weird people in that facility out of which I remember only one particularly. It was a dwarf with a baby attached to its stomach. The dwarf was hiding the baby under his clothes and revealed it only once when Arnold was escaping the facility along with kids. I guess these weird creatures had kidnapped those kids and Arnold came as to free them. I do not remember much about that movie but I saw it during late 90's I believe.

Comment: Any movies of Paul Verhoeven are eccentric.

Comment: Could it have been outreach footage of his time as California governor?

Comment: If it was 1990 Total Recall, I'm surprised the *one* creature you remember was a dwarf, not the three-breasted woman.

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104794/movie-with-people-on-mars-mars-atmosphere-has-a-problem-and-guy-saves-them-all

Comment: @Raystafarian that was Eccentrica Gallumbits, right? ;)

Comment: I don't remember Total Recall having kids in it. Kuato Wasn't attached to a dwarf, he was attached to George, played by Marshall Bell.

Answer (score 52):

[Total Recall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100802/?ref_=nv_sr_2), the 1990 version. The guy with the dwarf attached is a dead giveaway.

The thing with the big exhaust is a facility built by aliens that supposedly were able to create an atmosphere for Mars. The only detail that doesn't quite  match is the abduction thing.

The "creepy people" might be the mutated population of Mars (who where actually the good guys, leading a rebellion against an earthbound company that controlled all resources on Mars and wanted to prevent them from activating the alien machine).

This is an adaption of a [Philip Dick short story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Can_Remember_It_for_You_Wholesale) and has a [relatively recent remake](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386703/?ref_=nv_sr_1) starring Colin Farell.

Comment: http://mafab.hu/static/2014t/285/14/44105_54.jpg - KUATO LIVES!!

Comment: Were there kids in Total Recall?   I don't recall.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Did you go to Recall?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson, not really (a few small people who might have been confused with kids, though). Possibly the OP conflated Total Recall and the abduction of Arnies characters daughter in True Lies (the "creepy people" in that movie are Arabs).  But the belly-baby is pretty unique to Total Recall.

Comment: a remake with Colin Farrell, Jessica Biel, and friggin' Heisenberg...I'm gonna have to check that out some time

Comment: I can give the exact same answer as this, down to the person with the baby attached, and the abduction thing not quite matching, with [Hellboy II "The Golden Army"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellboy_II:_The_Golden_Army). Here's a picture of the baby: https://markbould.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/lexi-baby-tumor.jpg?w=660

Comment: @MrLister, not in the 90s and not with Schwarzenegger. But if you think it's a good fit you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Well, they might have mistaken the 00's for the 90's, and Ron Perlman for, ehm... you know what, I'll leave it as a comment.

Comment: I would call it "loosely based on ideas from" that story rather than "adaptation". Remake is even more loosely based on 1990 version, bearing almost no similarities to the original.

Comment: *based on* — really need a credit explaining that Dick provided an **infusion of originality** to the scriptwriters. Who were *still* not being original since they got it from someone else, but it's a different class of idea than the usual recycled plot formulas they use.

Comment: @Agent_L, sorry, native is not my native language. I assumed "adaptation" was the proper word for "using the name of the author and not much else".

Comment: @EikePierstorff there were a few kids in Total Recall -- my guess is that the OP is thinking about the mutant population that was being starved of oxygen towards the end of the movie, and Arnie's character was trying to save them: http://img.izismile.com/img/img4/20110629/640/childhood_actors_from_classic_movies_that_are_all_grown_up_640_99.jpg

Comment: @EikePierstorff Neither is mine. I'm just ranting about how much a good story was changed. Probably this is what "adaptation" means this days anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Thinking about this, I think you have got your Arnie movies all mixed up into one!

The dwarf was Danny DeVito in Twins, the kids were the school kids in Kindergarten Cop and the baby under the clothes was Kuato in the original Total Recall.

Comment: And *Commando*. That's the only one I can think of with a kidnapping.

Comment: @Mazura I'm sure we can squeeze Predator in there somewhere too!

Comment: And the facility is obviously the steel mill at the end of Terminator II. The weird people were the different guises of the T1000, and there was this kid.

Comment: If he had a sword, then we can include Conan the Barbarian too!